.NET 6 upgrade to .NET 8 using OIDC is now throwing error: "An invalid request URI was provided."
I have a fairly standard .NET 6 app that is using cookies for DefaultScheme and OIDC for the challenge scheme. I didn't change the registrations for either, I simply upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8.
I'm now getting an error after AuthorizationCode receipt. The OpenIdConnectEvents OnAuthenticationFailed event is firing with an error

An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set

Has anyone seen this after upgrading a working .NET 6 project to .NET 8?

After stepping through the Framework code, what I'm seeing is that the TokenEndpoint property isn't set from the IdP's Metadata.  For some reason all the other endpoints are being set, but token_endpoint appears to be ignored.

The issue is that the OpenIdConnectConfigurationSerializer is skipping every other token from the metadata.  This is described in these two issues in Github.  It's very surprising that not more people have hit this error since .NET 8.0 has been released.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/2546
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/2513
